# Setting endpoints to work when deployed Identity Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, identityserver4

I am building a React app and using Azure Web Apps for hosting. During development time I set my endpoints to localhost throughout my code, but this will not work when deployed as there is no concept of localhost when on Azure. How can I go about managing my endpoints between local and deployed environments? Do I have to do conditional checks during Startup and set a variable that I then reference, or is there an easier way to manage this?

Comment: Not sure I understand: You have actual `//localhost` url's in your code? Not relative paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from using relative paths (vs absolute paths prefixed with `localhost`), Azure Web Apps offers application settings which are settable outside of your app, and then read in through the environment (via your app).

Take a look under your Web App's application settings, where you can create various settings for your app. For example:

[image]

For local dev, you can have your own local environment settings e.g. `app_uri` = `localhost`, and for the deployed app, set to something like `https://some-address.com`, configured via Application Settings.

Comment: Thanks, I figured Environment settings might be the way I had to do this.